# Whats the best way to close a WCF thread?

Tags: c#, wcf, multithreading

I have an application which is taking ages to close. When I close the app, it tries to dispose a number of threads that do TCP scanning, WCF P2P attempts, and so on. The problem lies in a WCF thread that stalls on a method for about 17 seconds.

```
IP2PAuthenticationService server;
ChannelFactory<IP2PAuthenticationService> channelFactory;
channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IP2PAuthenticationService>(binding, endpointAddress);

server = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
string result = server.SendMyDetails(myContract, "foo");
```

So all this happens inside a thread. When the form closes it attempts to dispose the thread

```
 if (prospectCrawlerThread != null)
 {
      prospectCrawlerThread.Abort();
      //prospectCrawlerThread.Join();
      prospectCrawlerThread = null;
  }
```

I've confirmed this by uncommenting the `.Join()`, and also by pausing the debug and seeing the threads that are still running.

What's the best way to get rid of this thread?

Edit: setting the thread to background seemed to make it quicker
`prospectCrawlerThread.IsBackground = true;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IsBackgroundThread = true will abort the thread automatically when the form closes, so I think that's what you're looking for if you just want to kill it.

Comment: It will get the job done, however, I would build in some way of closing sockets on the FormClosing event of the application. Especially if you're the server side.

Answer (score 5):

It is worth pointing out that `Thread.Abort` is generally a bad practise and should be avoided:

> "aborting a thread is pure evil. Try to never do so!"
>      -- [*Eric Lippert, Fabulous Adventures In Coding*](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx)
>
> "Thread.Abort is a Sign of a Poorly Designed Program"
>      -- [*Peter Ritchie's MVP Blog*](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/08/22/thead-abort-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx)